# TsError and Firebase: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

**ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.usuarios = this.authService.getAll();
  let sub = this.authService.usuario$.subscribe(usuario =>{
    this.usuario = usuario;
    sub.unsubscribe
  })
  this.usuario = new Usuario()
    this.authService.usuario$.subscribe( usuario => {
      this.usuario = usuario
})
}
```

**config.ts**

```
setAdmin(usuario: Usuario) {
  const userRef =  this.afs.collection(`usuarios/`).doc(usuario.uid)
    .get()
      //.pipe(
      //   map(user =>{
      //     usuario = {
      //       roles:{
      //         admin: true,
      //         user: true,
      //       }
      //     }  
      //   })  
        
      // )
      
 
}
```

i'm trying set a admin role to a specific user in a firebase, but i just can do it using `this.usuario.uid` and just can set the role to the logged user, or if i use usuario.uid i get the return

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

***configs.html***

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" >
      <app-card [hidHeader]="true" cardClass="user-profile-list">
        <form >
        <div class="dt-responsive table-responsive">
          <table datatable class="table table-striped row-border table-hover">                
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>    
                <th>Tipo de Acesso</th>                      
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios | async">
              <td>
                <div class="d-inline-block align-middle">
                  <img [src]="usuario.photoURL || '/assets/images/image-placeholder.png'" alt="user image" class="img-radius align-top m-r-15" style="width:40px">
                  <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <h4 class="m-b-0">{{usuario.displayName}}</h4>
                    <p class="m-b-0">{{usuario.email}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
                    <button type="submit" (click)="setAdmin()" class="btn btn-success admin">Tornar Admin</button>
                    <button type="submit" (click)="removeAdmin()" class="btn btn-danger radmin">Remover admin</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              <td>  

                <span class="badge badge-light-success"></span>
                <div class="overlay-edit">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-success pos"><i class="feather icon-check-circle"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger pos"><i class="feather icon-trash-2"></i></button>
                </div>
              </td>           
            </tr>       
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>            
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
      </app-card>
    </div>
  </div>
```

that is the way i'm trying pass the setusuario

Comment: It sounds like `usuario` is undefined then. It's hard to say why that is, as we can't see how you call `setAdmin`, but you'll want to check in your code what the value is you are passing for `usuario` there..

Comment: Its like, on my init i receive all the users to put in a list, but when i try to set and update the afs.collection, say that doenst exist the usuario.uid on my firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i made a edit to show the HTML, i guess u can see what i want to do now

Comment: Your `setAdmin(usuario: Usuario)` expects that you pass a `usario` into it, yet when you call it inside the HTML, you don't pass anything in: `(click)="setAdmin()"`